# função file_exists do php - caminho relativo e absoluto

Tags: php, apache, arquivo, virtualhost

Em aplicações PHP, quando uso caminho absoluto, tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando uso caminho relativo, não funciona.

Um exemplo: na minha aplicação tenho de usar isso:

```
file_exists("/var/www/html/meus_projetos/dgnetwork/public_html/model/persistence/dao/dao_config/{$name}.ini")
```

No meu servidor local apache2, tenho um virtual hosts onde configuro o atributo `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/meus_projetos/dgnetwork/public_html`

Com isso eu imaginava que poderia usar o caminho absoluto a partir de public_html ou seja:

```
file_exists("model/persistence/dao/dao_config/{$name}.ini")
```

Porém não funcionou.

Será que alguém consegue me ajudar a organizar melhor isso?

Comment: Eu recomendaria que criasses um ficheiro de configuração com local fixo, onde irias colocar todos os caminhos para diretórios e subdiretórios do site/projeto incluindo o _root_, e que inicializasses estas configurações de uma só vez..

Answer (score 1):

A questão era mais simples que eu imaginei.
Ao iniciar a aplicação, é apenas eu dar um require em um arquivo, com essa classe constantes e a partir daí ela já estará na memória. 
Problema resolvido, obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa `file_exists("model/persistence/dao/dao_config/{$name}.ini")` ele vai buscar a partir do local onde esta o arquivo.

Você pode definir uma constante para a pasta raiz

```
define("DOCUMENT_ROOT", "/var/www/html/meus_projetos/dgnetwork/public_html/");
```

e depois usar desse jeito:

```
file_exists(DOCUMENT_ROOT."model/persistence/dao/dao_config/{$name}.ini")
```

Comment: assim vou ter replicação de código, e se eu definir uma classe de constantes - final class constantes {} - vou ter de adicionar o caminho absoluto , o que implicaria em ambiguidade.

Answer (score 0):

Funciona sem ser o caminho absoluto porem você pode ter problemas.

> Exemplo:

Tenho uma pasta chamada **a1** e dentro dela tenho o arquivo **verifica_permissao.php** ai na pasta que fica antes da **a1** você cria um arquivo teste e inclui o **verifica_permissao.php**, suponha-se que no verifica_permissão .php contenha o código abaixo:

```
<?php
   //Exemplo do verifica_permissao.php
   function verifica_permissao($arquivo) {
        return file_exists($arquivo);
   }
```

Ao tentar usa o verifica_permissao, caso você tente acessar um arquivo na pasta **a2** que esta no mesmo nível da **a1** ele vai retornar false mesmo que o arquivo exista porque ele tentaria acessar o seguinte endereço:

> /var/www/a1/a2/arquivo.txt

Ou seja considere criar uma variável identificando onde fica a raíz do seu projeto e sempre procure concatenando. Assim não haverá preocupação, olha um exemplo abaixo.

> Arquivo config.php

```
<?php

     DEFINE("ROOT_DIR", __DIR__);
```

> Arquivo teste.php

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';
    $arquivo = file_exists(ROOT_DIR . 'model/persistence/dao/dao_config/{$name}.ini');

    if($arquivo) {
        echo "Existe";
    } else {
        echo "Não existe.";
    }
```

**Respondendo sua pergunta:** Não, não é preciso colocar o caminho absoluto! Ele pega a partir de onde a função é chamada.

Comment: Isso foi de grande ajuda.
Mas e se eu quiser definir minhas constantes todas dentro de uma classe, dentro da minha aplicação ?
Uma classe - final class app_const {} ?
ai definiria um contrutor private
E as constantes ex: const DOCUMENT_ROOT = 'caminho'

Comment: pelo seu exemplo, percebi que vc dispões  os arquivos no mesmo diretório.
Mas e se tiver usando um padrão de projeto mais específico, onde uma ou mais classes em diretórios distintos precisem requerer o config.php.
COmo vai ficar a chamada ao arquivo ?????

Comment: como assim? não entendi

Comment: se você já definiu no apache, você pode pegar o caminho absoluto usando o vetor do $_SERVER exemplo:  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']